# Repetition metacharacters not allowed in positive lookbehind

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the statement

```
/(?<=.*)./.match("abc")
```

I get an error that there is an invalid pattern in the look behind.

Replacing `(?<=.*)` with `(?<=.)` yields an answer.

Similar issues occur when using `+` in place of `*`.

Why does the `*` [repetition metacharacter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition) cause an error to be thrown?

Using Ruby 2.5.0.

Comment: Ruby regex does not support variable width lookbehind patterns.

Comment: See the section "Important Notes About Lookbehind" [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).